# Querying firebase api by customer uid

Tags: google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to create a customized analytics dashboard for my customers. Is there a way to get the analytics data from google / firebase over a REST API filtered by customer uid, etc? Or do I have to track all the data by my own to create statistics for my customers.

To better understand my problem - I create a platform where people can promote their restaurants and I want to show them some statistics about their views, interactions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you'd be best served by [exporting the Analytics events to BigQuery](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export) and building your customer reports from that. That's not a direct API you can call from your app, but it gives you the most flexicility

Alternatively, you could use the [Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4). In its own words:

> The Google Analytics Reporting API v4 provides programmatic methods to access report data in Google Analytics (Universal Analytics properties only). With the Google Analytics Reporting API, you can:
>
> - Build custom dashboards to display Google Analytics data.
> - Automate complex reporting tasks to save time.
> - Integrate your Google Analytics data with other business applications.